# Copy existing data base (storage file) to storage folder

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

In my Windows Store App I want to copy existing data base to storage folder.
My data base placed on main folder of project.

For copy data table to storage folder I use following code ([link to article](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/import-an-already-existing-sqlite-database-in-a-windows-8-application/)):

```
 StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("people.sqlite");
 await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
```

And all works great in VS in debug mode.
But if I use release mode or just stop debug and open my app from Windows - it doesn't work. 
 Also no exception was thrown. App just freeze when try to call `CopyAsync`. 
 I'm sure, that my `databaseFile!=null` in release mode too.

Also I tried to get file like this:

```
var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///people.sqlite");
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```

But it doesn't solve my problem.

Question: What is the right way to copy existing data base to storage folder?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks guys for your answers, but I can't solve my problem(

I use CaliburnMicro for implementation MVVM.

On my view model when page `Loaded` I call:

```
private async Task PrepareDatabase()
        {
            bool isDatabaseExisting;
            var storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder; ;
            try
            {
                await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("database_name.sqlite");
                isDatabaseExisting = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                isDatabaseExisting = false;
            }
            if (!isDatabaseExisting)
            {
                StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("database_name.sqlite");
                await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
            }
        }
```

My database: 
`Name - database_name.sqlite;` 
`Build action - Content;`
 `Copy to Output Directory - Copy always;`

When I start app from visual studio - all works like it should. 
Then I stop debug, and run app from Windows - and it freeze, when it try to open this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the "Build Action" property, you'll find a property named "Copy To Output Directory". Make sure it is set to "Copy Always"

**EDIT:**

There is another way to include files with your project i.e. Embedded Resource.

In the properties, set the Build Action to "Embedded Resource".

```
using System.Reflection;


public MainPage()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();
  Assembly asm = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
  Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("YourNamespace.filename.extension");


  ConvertToFileAndCopyToLocalDirectory(stream);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I already try all types of "Copy to Output Directory" - and it still not work in release mode or if I run app from Windows (not from VS). May be you have another idea?

Comment: Check my edited answer. Check to see if you're getting a valid stream in release mode. If you are, you can convert the stream back into a file.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it not works for me. Check updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure why it would work in debug, I assume you've ensured that the applications package manifest includes a declaration for .sqlite files?

One other thing to check is perhaps if you already have a database by that name in the local folder. I would expect an exception but when I do my CopyAsync I use the overload to specify a filename and collision options:

```
await latestFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder,
    "My Db Name",
    NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Edit: As Arsalan00 mentioned, you can use embedded resources. I use these for testing by copying databases set as embedded resources using these two functions below:

```
    private const string DbBasePath = "MyApp.TestHelpers.TestDatabases.";    

    public static IAsyncOperation<IStorageFile> GetDbAsync(string dbName)
    {
        return Util.GetFileFromAssemblyResource(typeof(Data).GetTypeInfo().Assembly, DbBasePath + dbName, dbName, ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder).AsAsyncOperation();
    }

    public static async Task<IStorageFile> GetFileFromAssemblyResource(Assembly ass, string resource, string filenameToCreate, IStorageFolder location)
    {
        IStorageFile file;
        // read for embedded resources
        using (var stream = ass.GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
        {
            var buf = new byte[stream.Length];
            // create file
            file = await location.CreateFileAsync(DateTime.Now.Ticks + filenameToCreate, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                // read bytes at a time from the embedded resource
                while ((read = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    // write from memory into buffer
                    await memStream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, read);
                    // write buffer to file
                    await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, buf);
                }
            }
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it not works for me. Check updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems right to me. It should work.

I just have one concern:
Can you copy all the function and include how it will be called.

I assume that you lack of some await/async keyword somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

@jimpanzer I also faced the same issue and later figured out that the CopyAsync failed (when I ran the app, not while debugging) because a file with the same name existed. This db file was getting created from the code which is used to get the data when the db file is not availbale. May be you might also be doing the same. Cheers